# Web page requested through PHP returns a 404 error but when the same URL is accessed through a browser it works

Tags: php

I have tried accessing an API endpoint URL through both file_get_contents and the HTTP_Request class, but both return a 404 error.  However, the same URL is accessible through the browser.

It's worth noting that I am requesting a page on api.example.com, but the 404 page seems to be the one generated from www.example.com.

This code was working a week ago and I've just noticed it's now not working, so I don't know if it's something my hosting company has changed or if it's the site I am trying to interface with.

For what it's worth, here's my code, complete with everything I've tried so far (ie adding headers and allowing redirects):

```
    $url = 'http://api.example.com/a/b?api_key=abc123';
    $r = new HTTP_Request( $url, array( 'allowRedirects' => true ) );
    $r->addHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
    $r->addHeader('Accept-Encoding','gzip, deflate');
    $r->addHeader('Connection','keep-alive');
    $r->addHeader('Accept','text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
    $r->addHeader('Accept-Language','en-gb,en;q=0.5');
    $r->setMethod('GET');
    try {
        $r->sendRequest();
        if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
            return json_decode( $r->getResponseBody() );
        } else {
            // Always goes here!!
            print '<!-- ' . $r->getResponseCode() . ' -->';
        }
    } catch (HttpException $ex) {
        echo '<!-- ' . $ex . ' -->';
    }
```

Comment: if you give us the real site name, i can check it

Comment: The reason I haven't is because an API key is required and I'd rather not give mine out publicly

Comment: dont need the key to run a trace

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the DNS resolution failing.  Switching to the IP resolved it.  Thanks for your time, Dagon.